# How to use a testBit function to check a specific indexed bit in a binary array

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QByteArray` that I am pulling a hex number out of and I would like to break it down into individual bits. After doing this I want to do a bit test on a specific bit to check if its true to send a message out.

This is the code I have right now :

```
if(ID == 65290) {
    QBitArray a(Data_0,16);
    QString z = QString::number(Data_0,2);
    a.testBit(0) = b;
    if(b == true) {
        ui->Test->setText(z);
        m_workerThread->sendMsg(418381594,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    } else {
        m_workerThread->sendMsg(418381594,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        ui->Test->setText(z);
    }
}
```

This wont compile because I am not correctly using testBit I am sure. The QString is just so I can see the word as it is being converted to binary. Data_0 is being received elsewhere.

I am very new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of Qt but it seems you're trying to assign a value to a function call.

Try `b = a.testBit(0)` instead.

Question: You're creating an instance by means of a constructor to me unknown.
Does the compiler complain about the first line?

Comment: I have tried that and the program compiles and starts to run when deployed but then crashes with an error associated with that testBit. What I am attempting and failing to do is check the value of the first bit and if it is 1 or true then do something. If its not then do something else. testBit may not be the best solution I really don't know.

Comment: The parameter i passed to the method testBit() should be 0<=i<size(). Could you please verify the size of the bit array; maybe it's simply empty.

Comment: The bit array doesn't appear to be empty as the QString shows that there is a value populating in the array. With no input the array shows a 0.  As I understand it a 0 is acceptable as a place holder in the array.

Comment: inline bool QBitArray::testBit(int i) const
{ Q_ASSERT(uint(i) < uint(size()));
 return (*(reinterpret_cast<const uchar*>(d.constData())+1+(i>>3)) & (1 << (i & 7))) != 0; }
That is the function that is failing.

Comment: Please notice that 0 as input parameter is valid only if the array is not empty (the index should be smaller than the array size). Could you check the actual size by calling the method 'size()'?

Comment: I still don't understand your constructor call. The Qt documentation I got does not specify a constructor passing it a string and a number (which I suppose to be the base)

Comment: You may be correct. I tried this and it compiled and worked.           QBitArray a(2);
            a.setBit(0,true);
            QString z =QString::number(Data_0,2);

        if(a.testBit(0)==true)
            {
                ui->Test->setText(z);
                m_workerThread->sendMsg(418381594,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
            }
            else
            {
                m_workerThread->sendMsg(418381594,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
                ui->Test->setText(z);
            }

            }

Comment: I just made an array and set its index (0) to true and it is checking that and getting an answer. So my problem must be that the array is actually empty instead of populated with zeros when there is no number in it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm really curious about the constructor you're calling. Did I miss something? If you're question was answered, could you please vote it?

Comment: I tried to vote and I don't have high enough rep. Same for moving to chat. I truly don't know the jargon that comes with programming. I am out of my element but required to get this working for my job.  I am working with a CAN network where I am bringing a Hex can byte from a QByteArray and trying to turn it into a bit array and then check the individual bits to turn a light on or off. I hope that answers the question.